# How to lock function from parallel processing

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing, django-celery

I allowed 2 processes in celery and in each process 
There is a requirement for calling API request 
And it should not call at the same time. API server blocks concurrent request.
Can I lock that function if it is running in one process?

```
def getlocaionadress(geocode):
    address = get_address_from_db(geocode)
    if not address:
        address = fetchaddress(geocode)

def fetchaddress(geocode):
    address = sent_api_request(geocode)
    return address
```

I need to lock fetchaddress function if it is already called in one process.
How can I achieve this?
Is there any alternate mechanism to avoid parallel calling of API request running in multiple processes.
I am using celery==3.1.14, python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

You could coordinate with a [Lock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Lock).

Are you maybe saying you're not sure how to [wrap](http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/#_9_decorators) a function with a Lock [decorator](https://realpython.com/blog/python/primer-on-python-decorators/#real-world-examples)?